# How to set some days on Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK

Tags: java, calendar, java.util.calendar

I need to set some days in method set. I try to use:

```
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.WEDNESDAY);
```

but with this way set only Wednesday.

Thank you and sorry for my english :)

Comment: Could you provide more info on what you intend to do? `java.util.Calendar` is nothing like a Google Calendar or similar, it just represents a given datetime (maybe that is the origin of the confussion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Calendar` does not function as you expect it to.  From the JavaDoc:

> The Calendar class is an abstract class that provides methods for
>   converting between a specific instant in time and a set of calendar
>   fields such as YEAR, MONTH, DAY_OF_MONTH, HOUR, and so on, and for
>   manipulating the calendar fields, such as getting the date of the next
>   week. An instant in time can be represented by a millisecond value
>   that is an offset from the Epoch, January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT
>   (Gregorian).

Notice that the documentation states a `specific instant in time`.  This implies the `Calendar` can only be based off of one point in time from epoch.

When you use the `set` method you are adjusting the `specific instant in time` through each call.  So first it gets set to Monday then Wednesday.

You could use a `List<Calendar>` to store multiple `Calendar` instances set to your desired days.

```
public class CalendarTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
        cal2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.WEDNESDAY);

        List<Calendar> calendars = Arrays.asList(cal1, cal2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, and can I achieve that use different way?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getDay(String day,String month,String year){

    int mm = Integer.parseInt(month);
    int dd = Integer.parseInt(day);
    int yy = Integer.parseInt(year);
    LocalDate dt = LocalDate.of(yy, mm, dd);
    return dt.getDayOfWeek().toString().toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for demonstrating the use of the modern `LocalDate` class instead of the outdated and poorly designed `Calendar`. As I read the question, you didn’t quite hit what was asked about, though.